# Windows Server Firewall report

Tags: windows-server-2008, firewall

I am trying to get a list of all sites (ips) visited by a computer on the network. Is there a way to ask the Windows firewall to return me a report of all the sites for a specific IP address on the network (domain)?

Thanks

p.s: Am using Windows Server 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to turn on firewall logging for this to work, but yes, it looks like it's possible.  You'll want to set the firewall to record successful connections, as described in [this TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947815(WS.10).aspx#bkmk_ToenableWindowsFirewallandconfigurethedefaultbehavior), plus something to go through the logs afterwards and pull out the stuff you're interested in.

It seems an unusual way of doing it, though; do you really want the logging to take place on the same box that's doing the accessing?  I'd go for something outwith the server you want to monitor that could log connections from the server's IP instead.  Depending on what you use for that, it may also have the added benefit of being configurable so that it would just log HTTP/S connections, rather than all of them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Basically my setup is I have a server that is my proxy server and domain controller. I want to monitor all the traffic from all my clients in order to monitor usage and monitor the sites (I know about firewall rules but I just want to monitor the sites visited). I will check the article you mentioned.

Comment: Ah, with you now.  In that case the firewall thing should do, if you can't get whatever you're using as a proxy server to log it for you.

Comment: If you have a proxy server, you must process its log in order to collect sites accessed through it.